# How to show searched lines as well as number of occurrence of searched string?

Tags: text-processing, logs, search

I am working on a script which will show all the results and their count on the console based on a particular string .

Example:
Suppose I searched for a string called "ERROR", I got the below results, here number of ERROR occurrence is 5.

```
2013-12-08 13:43:07 SUSE::SRPrivate - [error]  ERROR: Couldn't connect to server: (7)
2014-01-08 13:43:06 SUSE::SRPrivate - [error]  ERROR: Couldn't connect to server: (7)
2014-02-08 13:43:24 SUSE::SRPrivate - [error]  ERROR: Timeout was reached: (28)
2014-03-08 13:43:03 SUSE::SRPrivate - [error]  ERROR: Couldn't connect to server: (7)
2014-04-08 13:43:24 SUSE::SRPrivate - [error]  ERROR: Timeout was reached: (28)
```

I want to show both logs and number of occurrences(lines). I wrote this below script to show the logs:

```
(zgrep -E "ERROR|Exception" $SS_HOME/logs/*.gz $PROBE_HOME/logs/*.gz $RELAY_HOME/logs/*.gz ;find . -type f -name "*.log" -exec cat {} +) | grep -F ERROR | sort
```

I don't know how to add the count the lines.
Please let me know for any additional information.

Answer (score 1):

To show matching lines, count them, and show the count, with `awk`:

```
awk '/ERROR/{err++; print} END{print "errors:", err}'
```

To summarize errors and exceptions:

```
awk '/ERROR/||/Exception/{faults++; print} END{print "faults:", faults}'
```

To count errors and exceptions separately:

```
awk '/ERROR/{err++; print} /Exception/{exc++; print}
     END{print "errors:", err, "exceptions:", exc}'
```

Note: The awk programs work as filter, they read from standard input and write to standard output, but you can also provide the data files as arguments. So to use is (as asked in the comment below) with one or more log-files use `awk '...' *.log`, or if you want one or more gz-files uncompressed before parsing them with `awk` use, e.g., `zcat *.gz | awk '...'` (where you substitute any of the above `awk` programs for `awk '...'`).

Comment: Hi Janis , thank you for the reply . if i want to search in .gz and .log file then how do i modify the command .

Comment: @user112232; I've added a note.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `wc` command with the `-l` option:

```
wc -l
```

If you wish to print the logs as well, then you can use `tee`:

```
cat logs.txt | grep -i error | tee >(wc -l)
```

Comment: if i am using this command , i can only see the number of counts but i want to show the logs also .

Comment: Answer has been updated as per your requirements.